# Pass Object value to for loop In Titanium

Tags: javascript, for-loop, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am new in titanium and want to display remote server data my object is

```
Object
 todo: Array[2]
  0: Object
   todo: "Khaleeq Raza"
   __proto__: Object
  1: Object
   todo: "Ateeq Raza"
  __proto__: Object
 length: 2
 __proto__: Array[0]
 __proto__: Object
  VM90:10
```

my code is in titanium to create rows and want to put data

```
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.109/read_todo_list.php", true);
    client.send();
    client.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if (client.readyState==4 && client.status==200)
        {

            json = JSON.stringify(client.response);
        var get=JSON.parse(json);

        for( var i=0; i<get.length; i++){

        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: get[i].todo,
            hasChild : true,
            });     
            dataArray.push(row);                
        }

        $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

        }

    };
```

but I am not getting any display what can b problem please help

Comment: You have posted the same question three times..

Answer (score 1):

There is no `XMLHttpRequest` in titanium, here is a simple way to get your data (assuming proper server configuration and no authentication).

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("Received json: " + this.responseText);
         // Parse JSON
         var object = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
         // Get the array
         var todo = object.todo;
         // Create table rows
         var dataArray = [];
         for( var i=0; i<todo.length; i++){
             var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                 title: todo[i].todo,
                 hasChild : true,
              });     
              dataArray.push(row);                
         }
         $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

         alert('success');
     },
     // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.debug(e.error);
         alert('error');
     },
     timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
 });
 // Prepare the connection.
 client.open("GET","http://192.168.1.109/read_todo_list.php");
 // Send the request.
 client.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this is creating problem and working fine with  XMLHttpRequest As I replied . What u say that XMLHttp should not use in Titanium although this is working.

Comment: please can u give me a suggestion about shopping cart in Titanium. I have Codiegniter app. I want to develop same like that in titanium is this is possible in Alloy to design HTML etc please suggest with thanks

Comment: you are right my code is run only in pc browser not in andriod app. but there is an errror: Failed to load resource: Request header field X-Titanium-Id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers